# nidaqmx co_channels can't write sample

Tags: python, nidaqmx

I try to use Ni-Daq to generate pulse. 
  the example provided by the nidaqmx is like as follows:

```
    import nidaqmx
from nidaqmx.types import CtrTime


with nidaqmx.Task() as task:
    task.co_channels.add_co_pulse_chan_time("Dev1/ctr0")

    sample = CtrTime(high_time=0.001, low_time=0.002)

    print('1 Channel 1 Sample Write: ')
    print(task.write(sample))
```

But after I run this script, it generate some errors as shown below:

> raise DaqError(error_buffer.value.decode("utf-8"), error_code) DaqError: 
>   The task is not buffered or has no channels.  If the task is
>   not buffered, use the scalar version of this function. If the task has
>   no channels, add one to the task. Task Name: _unnamedTask<0>
>
> Status Code: -201395

what cause the problem? how to fix that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What device model is "Dev1"?

Comment: the "Dev1" is NI PCI -6259.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python examples for NI-DAQmx are tuned for NI's X Series devices, the 6**3**xx models. The 6**2**xx models are M Series devices, and their counters are more picky about how you program them. In short: the pulse specification must be given when the channel is *created*, and cannot be given later. X Series devices do not have this restriction.

### Configuring the shape of the pulse

Instead of

```
task.co_channels.add_co_pulse_chan_time("Dev1/ctr0")
```

try

```
# https://github.com/ni/nidaqmx-python/blob/master/nidaqmx/_task_modules/co_channel_collection.py#L160
task.co_channels.add_co_pulse_chan_time(
    counter="Dev1/ctr0",
    low_time=0.002,
    high_time=0.001)
```

And because you specified the pulse in this way, you don't need to `write()` to the channel anymore. When you want to start the pulse train, just use

```
task.start()
```

### Configuring the length of the pulse train

When you generate a pulse train, you can tell the driver to emit a finite number of pulses or a continuous square wave.

Before you `start()` the task, use `cfg_implicit_timing()`. This snippet generates 1200 pulses:

```
# https://github.com/ni/nidaqmx-python/blob/master/nidaqmx/_task_modules/timing.py#L2878
pulse_count = 1200;
task.cfg_implicit_timing(
    sample_mode=AcquisitionType.FINITE,
    samps_per_chan=pulse_count)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I will try soon. In this case, is it possible to define how many pulse generated?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer to include that aspect as well.

Comment: Hi Joe, the code works. Thank you very much. now. how to do a loop of this pulse train? `for i in range(5): task.start()`

Comment: the code 'for i in range(5): task.start()' try to generate pulse_count 5 times, but this code doesn't work.

Comment: NI calls the behavior you're describing "retriggerable". You can either (1) create, configure, run, and clear the task each iteration; or (2) use an external signal, configure the start trigger on that pin, and enable its retriggerable property `task.triggers.start_trigger.cfg_dig_edge_start_trig("/Dev1/PFI9"); task.triggers.start_trigger.retriggerable = True;`

Comment: Kinda tacky, but if this works for you, would you mind accepting this answer?