# nidaqmx co_channels can't write sample and write samples continuesly

Tags: python, python-2.7, nidaqmx

As suggested in this post [nidaqmx co_channels can't write sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951166/nidaqmx-co-channels-cant-write-sample)

I am able to run my python script but when i include this function `cfg_implicit_timing()` Python throws the error saying that

> AttributeError: 'Task' object has no attribute 'cfg_implicit_timing'.

My requirement is to generate the pulses continuously and when ever user requests for change in the frequency it should change frequency of pulse output.

And i can't put the while loop to generate the pules continuously as i am monitoring digital and analog inputs also.

Is there any function which I will call one and and i specify the pulse generation timing and it generates continuously with out a while or for loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to specify the timing, you have to call it like this:

```
Task.timing.cfg_samp_clk_timing(rate= fs_write, sample_mode=nidaqmx.constants.AcquisitionType.CONTINUOUS)
```

I set the AcquisitionType as CONTINUOUS to get a not ending Signal.